# Error in Downloading live pdf file from URL in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to download a [pdf](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-552-storage-guide.pdf) file with below Python function. I was able to open that [URL](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-552-storage-guide.pdf)(redirect to another URL) in the browser. But the code is getting 404 error.

```
import requests
 def downloadFile(url, fileName):
        r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, stream=True)
        with open(fileName, "wb") as pdf:             
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                if chunk:
                    pdf.write(chunk)


downloadFile("http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-552-storage-guide.pdf", "vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-552-storage-guide.pdf")
```

Comment: If you're getting a 404 you're probably being redirected to somewhere else because your code is being picked up as a scraper bot (some sites don't support that).  Try adding a header and see if it changes the response.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using the redirected url directly?

Comment: @Idlehands which header qualifies it to treat as normal request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few websites block based on language or location. Following code with additional header works

```
In [11]: def downloadFile(url, fileName):
         headers = {'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,te;q=0.8'}
         r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, stream=True, headers=headers)
        with open(fileName, "wb") as pdf:             
           for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
               if chunk:
                    pdf.write(chunk)

In [12]: downloadFile("http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-552-storage-guide.pdf", "vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-552-storage-guide.pdf")
```